# I keep recieving a collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

I am having a bit of a problem. I keep receiving a "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" every time I try to compile my program. I googled this, looked at examples, and saw that it usually occurs when a header file is not used correctly; however, I did not use header files in my code so I am not sure why it is doing this. I think this would be helpful for others who get this error and don't understand why. I do know that there are a lot of errors in my code, but I am trying to get to where I can compile it and work out all the kinks. Thanks a bunch!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_t {
    double x;
    struct node_t *next;
};

struct node_t *create_node(double n);
void print_node (struct node_t * node ); 
void print_list (struct node_t * head );
struct node_t * insert_head (struct node_t *head , struct node_t * node );
struct node_t * insert_tail (struct node_t *head , struct node_t * node );
struct node_t * insert_middle (struct node_t *head , struct node_t *node , int pos );
int count_nodes (struct node_t * head );
struct node_t * delete_node (struct node_t *head , double n);
void delete_list (struct node_t * head ); 

int main (void) 
{

    double n;
    int pos;


/** Asks the user what they would like to do. */

    printf("Please select an option: ");
    printf("1. Enter a number ");
    printf("2. Delete a number ");
    printf("3. Print all numbers ");
    printf("4. Tell how many items in the list ");
    printf("5. End program ");
    printf("Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): ");
    while ((tmp = getchar()) != '\n')
        in = tmp; /** Tells the compiler to use the number that the use put in. */

    switch (in){
    case '1': {/** If the user chooses Enter a Number, go through this process. */
        printf("1. Enter item at head of list ");
        printf("2. Enter item in middle of list ");
        printf("3. Enter item at tail of list ");
        printf("Please enter your choice (1,2,3): ");
        while ((tmp = getchar()) != '\n')
            in = tmp;

        switch (in) {
        case '1':{
            printf("Enter the number to be entered at head: ");

            fgets(s, 1024, stdin);

            struct node_t * create_node (double n);
            struct node_t *insert_head(struct node_t *head, struct node_t *node);

            break;
            }

        case '2':{
            printf("Enter the number to be entered in middle: ");

            fgets(s, 1024, stdin);

            struct node_t * create_node (double n);
            struct node_t * insert_middle (struct node_t *head , struct node_t *node , int pos);
            break;
            }

        case '3':{
            printf("Enter the number to be entered at tail: ");

            fgets(s, 1024, stdin);

            struct node_t * create_node (double n);
            struct node_t *insert_tail(struct node_t *tail, struct node_t *node);

            break;
            }
        break;
            }
        }   

    case '2':{/** If the user selected Delete a Number, go through this process. */ 

        printf("Enter the node that needs to be deleted: ");

        fgets(s, 1024, stdin);

        struct node_t * delete_node (struct node_t *head , double n);

        break;

        }   

    case '3':{/** If the user selected Print All Numbers, go through this process. */

        //void print_list (struct node_t *head)

        break;

        }

    case '4':{ /** If the user selected Tell How Many Items in the List, go through this process. */
        int count_nodes (struct node_t * head );        

        break;
        }

    case '5':{ /** If the user selected End Program, go through this process. */

        return 1;       

        break;
        }

    }       

    return 0;

}







/** Creates a new node
 *  @param double n, a number n
 *  @return pointer
 */

struct node_t * create_node (double n)
{


    struct node_t *p = malloc (size of (struct node_t))
    p -> x = n;
    p -> next = NULL; /*initializes pointer to null*/
    return p;
}


/** Prints the nodes
 *  @param struct node_t *node
 */
//void print_node (struct node_t *node )
//{
//  prints out the node and the address of the node
//  print(*node, &node)
//}


/** Prints list
 *  @param struct node_t *head
 */
//void print_list (struct node_t *head)
//{
//  print contents of list. both the doubles and the address.
//  while (pointer is pointing to something, keep going through the list. )
//  print(nodes in list, address of nodes )
//}


/** Inserts a node at the head
 *  @param struct node_t *head, the structure where head is. 
 *  @param struct node_t *node, the structure where node is.
 *  @return head.
 */
struct node_t *insert_head(struct node_t *head, struct node_t *node)
{
    node-> next = head;
    head = node;
    return head;
}


/** Inserts a node at the tail.
 *  @param struct node_t *tail, the structure where tail is. 
 *  @param struct node_t *node, the structure where node is.
 *  @return head.
 */
struct node_t *insert_tail(struct node_t *tail, struct node_t *node)
{

    struct node_t *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
        head = node;
        return head;
    while (p->next ! = NULL)
        p = p-> next;
        p-> next = node;
        return head;
}


/** Inserts a node at the middle.
 *  @param struct node_t *head, the structure where head is. 
 *  @param struct node_t *node, the structure where node is.
 *  @param int pos, the position of the current node.
 *  @return head.
 */
struct node_t * insert_middle (struct node_t *head , struct node_t *node , int pos);
{

    int pos = 1;
    struct node_t *p = head;
    *head = pos, pos = 1;
    if (pos > SIZE )
        p-> next = node;
    else if (pos < 1)
        printf("Error\n");
    return head;
}


/** Counts the number of nodes
 *  @param struct node_t *head, the structure where head is. 
 *  @return count.
 */
int count_nodes (struct node_t * head );
{

    struct node_t *p = head;
    while(p->next ! = NULL)
        return count;
    if (head == NULL)
        count = 0;
    return count;
}   

/** Deletes nodes
 *  @param struct node_t *head, the structure where head is. 
 *  @param double n, a number n.
 *  @return head.
 */ 
struct node_t * delete_node (struct node_t *head , double n);
{

    if (node == head)
        free head;
        p->next = head; //head now points to the pointer that was next after the node that was deleted

    else if (node == middle)
        free node;
        p = p->next //pointer before node that was deleted now points to node that was after deleted node

    else if (node == tail)
        free p = p->next = node; //free the last node that holds data. The node before it now points to NULL
        p->next = NULL;

    else printf("Error\n")
    return head;
}


/** Deletes list
 *  @param struct node_t *head, the structure where head is. 
 *  @return head.
 */ 
void delete_list (struct node_t * head ); 
{
    while((p->next ! = NULL)
        free head; //This will lose all memory after head.
        head == NULL;
    if (head == NULL) 
        return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing more problems than just a linker error... `tmp` isn't defined, for example.

Comment: When I try to compile this code, it doesn't even get close to the linker... What compiler are you using? There are syntax errors everywhere.

Comment: I am using gcc with -g -Wall flags. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ninjamonkeym: you should copy/paste the command and the output from the compile & link steps.  it also might be a good idea to add information about the version of the tools and the platform you're using.

Comment: gcc as well, I think something must have gotten lost in the copy/paste. Cause there's a space breaking up a `!=` somewhere in there and incorrect semicolons after function names lower down. `delete_node` has one, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That is when the linker fails.

Likely you have a mismatch between the signature of the forward declarations at the top of your file and the implementations below. The linker cannot find one of the functions.