# I am using Dev-C++ and receiving a compiler error saying "collect2.exe" is receiving status of 1

Tags: c++, windows, oop, compiler-errors, makefile

I have read other posts regarding this error but I have not been able to solve my problem. It could be something obvious with my code, but the code seems fine to me. The compiler log output is:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Durham Courses\Summer 2015\OOP Object-Oriented Programming\Dev CPP Directory\Makefile.win" all

g++.exe cash.o main.o -o Lab3Functions.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc

main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `cash(double, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&)'

cash.o:cash.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Durham Courses\Summer 2015\OOP Object-Oriented Programming\Dev CPP Directory\Makefile.win:25: recipe for target 'Lab3Functions.exe' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [Lab3Functions.exe] Error 1

Compilation failed after 0.91 seconds with errors
```

Could it be this multiple definition bit toward the end? What I've done (as per my assignment) is created one file (cash.cpp) which contains the definition of cash function and then I've got:

```
#include "cash.cpp"
```

at the top of my main. Is that not correct?

Comment: Generally you `#include` header files and not `.cpp` files. Whether that's an error depends on how you compiled things. Given that you compiled an independent `cash.o` file and then tried to link `cash.o` and `main.o` together, yes, that is likely wrong and the cause of the problem.

Comment: @MichaelLongauer Why use Dev C++, Use CodeBlocks or Visual Studio .

Comment: @Etan Reisner Are you saying it would be better to write a header file that includes a prototype/reference to cash.cpp?

Comment: That would be the normal way to do it, yes. Either that or don't bother compiling `cash.o` on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I tried simulating your issue:

Here is my test.cpp with the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cash.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  printf("%d",cash());
  return 0;
}

And here is  cash.cpp:

int cash()
{
    return 10;
}
```

And 10 is the output.

Your cash.cpp and the main file must be in the same directory. And ensure only one such file is in the same directory.

Also it could be related to C Drive privileges on Windows. 
In that case a workaround can be found here: [Dev C++ compilation error, permission denied.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463958/dev-c-compilation-error-permission-denied)

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848533/i-keep-recieving-a-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status) (Possible linker failure). Check that the forward declarations of the function are consistent with the definition.

Comment: Both files are in the same directory and I believe ar eht eonly ones named such. I tried bring the function defined in cash.cpp in the main.cpp using a prototype and itt compiles and runs, so I believe we are on the right track. Something about the way it's being included is wrong

Comment: @MichaelLongauer try a dummy function like i did, and see if the linker works.

Comment: Okay, moved all files to a separate folder to ensure they were isolated. Double checked forward declarations (i.e. arguments match parameters in method signature) and those are fine. Wrote:

    void dummy() {

        cout << "blah";

    }

But that's still saying it has multiple definitions in the compile log, and that's without even calling it in the main.

Comment: How did you compile this? You need to compile `cash.o` and `main.o` and then try to link them together to see the failure.

Comment: All I did was hit compile in the environment. I'm not seeing alternatives to that. I'm not sure to how to handle the '.o' files - all I did was write the source files (.cpp) and hit compile. Ive tried viewing the '.o' files and they are quite illegible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a header file which contained the definitions for the functions in my `main()`. I used `#ifndef` to get around the multiple definitions problem.

My assignment required the use of a `.cpp` but I can't get it to work, so at least this compiles and runs. Thank you all for your help!